# How to scroll a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div class = "W" scrollable but i failed to do it.
Need  Help Thanks in advance.

```
<div style = "visibility:hidden" id = "Box">
    <div style = "background-color: green" "border: solid" "width: 50px" id = "H" onclick  = "ok()" ><center><center><button class = "C" onclick = cross() >X</button></div>
    <div class= "F">
        <div class= "W" style = 'border:solid 100px' 'width:100px' ></div>
        <input type = "text" id = "I" size = "30px"  onchange = "go()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry sir i didn't understood what does fiddle means?

Comment: Can you please create demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ , so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks sir for giving the advice but i never user fiddle that's why its become problem for me to use fiddle. Besides i just want to scrabble my W class div you can ignore the java script methods. :)

Comment: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/5eJ6u/ you will get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vRDz5/)**

You made few very basic mistakes:

**1)** You are separating inline styles wrong:

```
style = "background-color: green" "border: solid" "width: 50px"
```

They should be separated by semicolon like this:

```
style = "background-color: green; border: solid; width: 50px"
```

**2)** You also forgot to open and close the center tag properly.

**3)** There was visibility hidden style on parent div which wasn't rendering the HTML at all!.

**Making Div Scrollable** To make the "w" div scrollable you must restrict its height then use overflow scroll property like this:

```
style="border:solid 100px; width:100px; height: 500px; overflow-y: auto;"
```

Comment: Another question sir
I cant control the length of the div How to do that ? :(

Comment: use `width` & `height` property to control dimensions.